# Ignoring Entity Property ([NotMapped]) using fluentAPI

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, code-generation, dbcontext

I am using "Entity Framework Reverse POCO Code First Generator" to generate my EF 6.1.3 entities.  I love the tool since it lets me just configure few properties in the generator file itself and customize my entities and context quite easily.  But now I am running into a problem.  In one of my SQL 2012 tables, I have a column "SocialSecurity" that is defined as a varbinary for security reasons.  I want to ignore this column in my generator completely.  I don't want this property appearing in my generated entity nor I want it in my EntityTypeConfiguration derived configuration class.  I have tried to "Ignore" this property both in the "InitializePartial() partial method as well as OnModelCreatingPartial() method of my DbContext class.  But no matter what I do, the Property SocialSecurity appears both in my Entity class and also in the Fluent API configuration class.  Can someone please show me how to ignore this property?

Here is my Generated Entity Configuration Class.  I am only going to post the relevant lines of code for both brevity and company code privacy.  I have also obfuscated the table names - Sorry!!

```
    public partial class AAAAAAConfiguration : System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<AAAAAA>
{
    public AAAAAAConfiguration(): this("dbo")
    {
    }

    public AAAAAAConfiguration(string schema)
    {
        ToTable("AAAAAA", schema);
        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName(@"ID").IsRequired().HasColumnType("bigint").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(x => x.SocialSecurity).HasColumnName(@"SocialSecurity").IsOptional().HasColumnType("varbinary");
        Property(x => x.Status).HasColumnName(@"Status").IsOptional().IsUnicode(false).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(10);
        Property(x => x.IsInactive).HasColumnName(@"IsInactive").IsRequired().HasColumnType("bit");
        Property(x => x.CreatedById).HasColumnName(@"CreatedByID").IsRequired().HasColumnType("bigint");
        Property(x => x.CreatedDate).HasColumnName(@"CreatedDate").IsRequired().HasColumnType("datetime");
        Property(x => x.UpdatedById).HasColumnName(@"UpdatedByID").IsRequired().HasColumnType("bigint");
        Property(x => x.UpdatedDate).HasColumnName(@"UpdatedDate").IsRequired().HasColumnType("datetime");
        Property(x => x.TimeStamped).HasColumnName(@"TimeStamped").IsRequired().IsFixedLength().HasColumnType("timestamp").HasMaxLength(8).IsRowVersion().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);

        InitializePartial();
    }
    partial void InitializePartial();
}
```

and here is my partial method InitializePartial()

```
    public partial class AAAAAAConfiguration
{
    partial void InitializePartial()
    {
        Ignore( x => x.SocialSecurity );
    }
}
```

Here is my generated DbContext class:

```
    public partial class BBBBBBDbContext : DataContext
{
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<AAAAAA> AAAAAAs { get; set; } // AAAAAA
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<AAAAAAAddress> AAAAAAAddresses { get; set; } // AAAAAAAddress

    public BBBBBBDbContext()
        : base("Name=BBBBBBDbContext")
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<BBBBBBDbContext>(null);
        InitializePartial();

    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public bool IsSqlParameterNull(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter param)
    {
        var sqlValue = param.SqlValue;
        var nullableValue = sqlValue as System.Data.SqlTypes.INullable;
        if (nullableValue != null)
            return nullableValue.IsNull;
        return (sqlValue == null || sqlValue == System.DBNull.Value);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AAAAAAConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AAAAAAAddressConfiguration());

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    public static System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder CreateModel(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder, string schema)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AAAAAAConfiguration(schema));
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AAAAAAAddressConfiguration(schema));
        return modelBuilder;
    }

    partial void InitializePartial();
    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

and here is my partial dbContext class and the partial method in it.

```
    public partial class BBBBBBDbContext
{
    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AAAAAA>().Ignore( x => x.SocialSecurity );
    }
}
```

Here is my generated entity (again, removed unnecessary code). As you can see the Property SocialSecurity is still in there.  I want it gone.

```
    public partial class AAAAAA : EntityBase
{
    public long Id { get; set; } // ID (Primary key)
    public byte[] SocialSecurity { get; set; } // SocialSecurity
    public string Status { get; set; } // Status (length: 10)
    public bool IsInactive { get; set; } // IsInactive
    public long CreatedById { get; set; } // CreatedByID
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } // CreatedDate
    public long UpdatedById { get; set; } // UpdatedByID
    public System.DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; } // UpdatedDate
    public byte[] TimeStamped { get; set; } // TimeStamped (length: 8)

    public AAAAAA()
    {
        IsInactive = false;
        CreatedById = 0;
        CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        UpdatedById = 0;
        UpdatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        InitializePartial();
    }

    partial void InitializePartial();
}
```

and finally, here is my generated configuration file.  Here too, you will still notice the Property SocialSecurity being addressed and setup.

```
    public partial class AAAAAAConfiguration : System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<AAAAAA>
{
    public AAAAAAConfiguration() : this("dbo")
    {
    }

    public AAAAAAConfiguration(string schema)
    {
        ToTable("AAAAAA", schema);
        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName(@"ID").IsRequired().HasColumnType("bigint").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(x => x.SocialSecurity).HasColumnName(@"SocialSecurity").IsOptional().HasColumnType("varbinary");
        Property(x => x.Status).HasColumnName(@"Status").IsOptional().IsUnicode(false).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(10);
        Property(x => x.IsInactive).HasColumnName(@"IsInactive").IsRequired().HasColumnType("bit");
        Property(x => x.CreatedById).HasColumnName(@"CreatedByID").IsRequired().HasColumnType("bigint");
        Property(x => x.CreatedDate).HasColumnName(@"CreatedDate").IsRequired().HasColumnType("datetime");
        Property(x => x.UpdatedById).HasColumnName(@"UpdatedByID").IsRequired().HasColumnType("bigint");
        Property(x => x.UpdatedDate).HasColumnName(@"UpdatedDate").IsRequired().HasColumnType("datetime");
        Property(x => x.TimeStamped).HasColumnName(@"TimeStamped").IsRequired().IsFixedLength().HasColumnType("timestamp").HasMaxLength(8).IsRowVersion().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);

        InitializePartial();
    }
    partial void InitializePartial();
}
```

So, how can I make the generator to totally ignore this column to show up anywhere in the entity or in the configuration.  If that is too difficult, what would be an alternative.  I certainly don't want to modify the generated classes since they will be replaced by the generator every time I run it.

Comment: Isn't the idea of a *code-first* generator that it creates your model once and then you continue working code first?

Comment: Well, it is code first from an existing database.  Since I have to live with an existing database, I have to find a way to work around this issue.

Comment: That doesn't mean you should always generate your model from the database. It means you modify the database and the class model separately. No doubt you will get an increasing number of customizations that you don't want to be blown away by a new code generation. In fact, usually the first modifications start right after the code was generated (like removing navigation properties you don't want, renaming generated properties, you name it).